# How to type multi font in text box and save it in MySql

Tags: php

How to type multi language  style in text box and save it in MySql using PHP

it's possible to give me any Idea ..

Comment: A text box accepts text, text does not know about fonts or similar. It is "plain text". If you require styled text, then you have to use some kind of markup notation, be it html or markdown or whatever. You _can_ save such in a database, since it is text again. But obviously it is much more effort to input such markup.

Comment: this not style ... value set as into the form

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand your last comment. To me using fonts and the like is styling of text. A html text input field does not support that natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) library like CKEditor http://ckeditor.com/

Those libraries helps you to edit formatted text, and then you can save the markup code on MySQL or wherever you want.